Переиспользовать значение из одной колонки когда две другие совпадают. Google Sheets
Извиняюсь если криво задал вопрос.
Вот есть такая таблица.
столбцы orderID_old и orderID_new имеют повторяющиеся значения. 4 и 2.
Нужно чтобы в number_new отобразились значения из number_old
вот так

гарантируется что пары  value и orderId не повторяются и уникальны.

подобрал формулу
= ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ВПР (D3; $A$2:$B$4 ; 2; ЛОЖЬ); "")
